# Event not found on type

Tags: c#, events, weakeventmanager

I have following exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Event' event not found on type 'ConsoleApplication.ITest'.

in this repro:

```
using System.Windows; // add reference to WindowsBase

interface IBase
{
    event EventHandler Event;
}

interface ITest : IBase { }

class Test : ITest
{
    public event EventHandler Event;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        WeakEventManager<IBase, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "Event", (s, e) => { }); // works
        WeakEventManager<ITest, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "Event", (s, e) => { }); // exception
    }
}
```

Why *inherited* via interfaces event can't be found? Exception is thrown from [this method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManagerT.cs,e2384e151a77a9bf).

Comment: Looks like the WeakEventManager looks only for events **specifically** in the specified type - when I have declared another event in ITest interface and tried to add it - it worked just fine.
It seems you need to provide the top-most (in inheritance hierarchy) type in order to find the event.

But **why** is that so - I fall short here.

Comment: @jakub-jankowski, it seems like a bug, because `typeof(ITest).GetEvent("Event")` works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried various combinations about your example. Here comes the only working code down here. It seems you need to know where the event is defined specificaly in the inheritance hierarchy.

```
using System.Reflection;
using MS.Internal.WindowsBase;

namespace EventTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();
            WeakEventManager<IBase, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "IBaseEvent", (s, e) => { }); // works
            WeakEventManager<ITest, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "ITestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // works 
            WeakEventManager<Test, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "TestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // works
        }
    }
    interface IBase
    {
        event EventHandler IBaseEvent;
    }

    interface ITest : IBase { event EventHandler ITestEvent; }

    class Test : ITest
    {        
        public event EventHandler IBaseEvent;
        public event EventHandler ITestEvent;
        public event EventHandler TestEvent;
    }
}
```

Whole combinations so far ;

```
            WeakEventManager<IBase, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "IBaseEvent", (s, e) => { }); // works
            WeakEventManager<IBase, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "ITestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // exception 
            WeakEventManager<IBase, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "TestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // exception

            WeakEventManager<ITest, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "IBaseEvent", (s, e) => { }); // exception
            WeakEventManager<ITest, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "ITestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // works 
            WeakEventManager<ITest, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "TestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // exception

            WeakEventManager<Test, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "IBaseEvent", (s, e) => { }); // exception
            WeakEventManager<Test, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "ITestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // exception 
            WeakEventManager<Test, EventArgs>.AddHandler(test, "TestEvent", (s, e) => { }); // works
```

Comment: I guess any other combination will fail?

Comment: @Sinatr, i added all combinations that i tried to my answer since it was too long to comment =)